# PHP twig conditional filter

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Let's say I have something like this:

`<img src='{{ asset(article.image.path) | imagine_filter('watermarked') }}' />`

what I want to do is apply `imagine_filter('watermarked')` only if `article.isWatermarked()` equals to `true`.

Is there any slicke way of doing this? Or I'm stuck with

```
{% set src = asset(article.image.path) %}
{% if article.isWatermarked() %}
{% set src = asset(article.image.path) | imagine_filter('watermarked') %}
{% endif %}
<img src='{{ src }}' />
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
<img src='{{ article.isWatermarked() ? asset(article.image.path) | imagine_filter('watermarked') : asset(article.image.path) }}' />
```

See ternary operator in doc: https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#other-operators

Comment: Looks good, didn't know this operator existed, let's see if there is even better approach :).

Comment: Only other aproach would be using a `Twig_SimpleFunction` or `Twig_SimpelFilter`

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how many places you need that functionality in you could put it in a macro:

macros.twig:

```
{%- macro wmImage(article) -%}
    {%- set src = article.watermarked ? asset(article.image.path) | imagine_filter('watermarked') : asset(article.image.path) -%}
    <img src="{{ src }}"/>
{%- endmacro -%}
```

In your template(s):

```
{%- import 'macros.twig' as 'macros' -%}

Usage:
{{ macros.wmImage(article) }}
```

Comment: Not a huge fan of macro's for only one line of code but it does the job